# Weak limit of invariant measures

Tags: measure-theory, dynamical-systems

Let $([0,1],F)$ be a dynamical system. Which hypotheses do I need on $F$ to be sure that a measure which is weak limit of a sequence of finitely supported $F$-invariant measures is an $F$-invariant measure? In particular, is Baire 2 sufficient? Is Baire 1 sufficient? Is left-continuous sufficient?

Comment: What is the link beetween $F$ and your sequence of finitely supported measures?

Comment: I have clarified this.

Comment: A second question: what is THE weak limit ? A sequence of measure can have infinitely many weak limit. Do you assume there is just one?

Comment: No, I meant any weak limit. I edited accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

All Baire function are measurable function.

Then if you take $A$ a measurable set, and if we name $\mu_n \to^* \mu$ the sequence of measure and its weak limit we have : $$
\mu_n(F^{-1}A)=\mu_n(A) \to \mu(A) = \mu(F^{-1}A) 
$$
So $\mu$ is also $F$-invariant. In conclusion to be measurable is enough (and a fortiori any Baire).

Comment: Define $Q_k$ as the set of rationals in $(0,1]$ whose denominator is $2^k$ ($k\in\mathbb{N}$). Take $T(x)=x$ for $x\in \cup_k Q_k$, $T(x)=0$ otherwise. Let $\mu_k$ be the measure concentrated and equidistributed on $Q_k$. The sequence $\mu_k$ weakly converges to the Lebesgue measure $\lambda$, and every $\mu_k$ is invariant for $T$. However  $\lambda(0)=0$ and $\lambda(T^{-1}(0))=\lambda([0,1]\setminus \cup_k Q_k)=1$. Where am I wrong?

Comment: $\mu_k$ do not weakly converge to Lebesgues measure, you write yourself the demonstration. It converge to a measure support on a Cantor set.

Comment: No, it doesn't. I'll be more explicit as probably there is some ambiguity in the description: $\mu_k$ is supported on $\{\frac{1}{2^k},\frac{2}{2^k},\dots,\frac{2^k}{2^k}=1\}$, each atom has the same measure and $\int_{[0,1]}d\mu_k=1$.